# How to display text with two different formats simultaneously using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am trying to do something similar to [softwaremaniacs.org](http://softwaremaniacs.org/playground/showdown-highlight/) or stackoverflow. When you ask a question, it displays what you write twice, one with a normal text format and the other one with a different format (Markdown).

In order to implement that, my first thought was:
Using JQuery keyup, send the text through AJAX POST to my Django url, then render the text and send it to a template that will display it as Markdown format.

Looking at the Network Response in the developer tools in my browser, this seems to work, but for some reason it doesn't display (update) the content.

Here are some snippets of my code

## AJAX

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post/blog/",
        data: { 
            'input_text' : $('#input').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

## views.py

```
def post_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST['input_text']
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'input_text': text})
```

## blog/post.html

```
{% load markup %}
<tr>
    <td id="input">
        <p>{{ input_text|markdow }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending it all the way back to the server? Why not use [Showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) to render the markdown in the user's browser.

Comment: I have never used it. I will check it out. Thank you!